`MaxListenersExceededWarning` when making subscriptions with `@solana/web3.js` version >=2
When using the subscriptions API in @solana/web3.js version >=2, I encounter this warning.
> (node:647037) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventTarget memory leak detected. 11 foo listeners added to EventTarget. MaxListeners is 10. Use events.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

How do I resolve it?

The subscriptions API implementation in @solana/web3.js version >=2 uses the EventTarget API to implement publish/subscribe channels internally. It's a useful primitive that lets you attach listeners for named events, and to broadcast events to those listeners.
The Node runtime decided to log a warning any time you attach a listener to an EventTarget more than 10 times.
const target = new EventTarget();
for (let ii = 0; ii < 11; ii++) {
  target.addEventListener('foo', () => {});
}

Their assumption was that people will only attach one or a very small number of listeners to any given target, and that any more than that indicates a failure to detach listeners when they are no longer needed – a failure that may lead to retain cycles that cause memory leaks.
This assumption is false where the design of @solana/web3.js is concerned. It attaches many listeners to the same target to implement efficient and low-overhead notification fanout. You can inspect the implementation here.
What you can do
Option 1
Ignore the warning. Go outside. Play with a dog. Lie in the grass and watch the clouds.
Option 2
In the entrypoint of your application, you can increase the maximum number of listeners before which a warning will not be triggered.
import { setMaxListeners } from 'node:events';

setMaxListeners(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);

Option 3
You can upgrade to whatever version of @solana/web3.js incorporates this change: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/issues/3624
